# Excel filtering on multiple columns

Tags: excel, filter

Apologies if this has been asked and answered but I haven't managed to find a match.

I have built a spreadsheet that lists all the movies in my collection. In that I have two columns that contain the Genres and four that list up to that number of principle actors like this...

[image: picture of ss layout]

A given genre can appear in either of those two columns D & E. An actor's name in any one of columns G,H,I,J. What I want to be able to do is have a filter that shows all the values across all the relevant columns in a drop-down list, as you get when you filter a single column. In other words, when I click the filter for Genre it shows 'drama' in the drop-down whether 'drama' is in column D or E and if selected shows results where it's in either column. Similar for actors names.

Is it possible to achieve this? I know I can use advanced filter to build an 'OR' query across column D & E but as far as I can see there's no way of making that list the available values across the columns and allow a choice - you have to know in advance what you are looking for.

You should also know I'm running an old release (2007) of Excel so any answer ideally has to work in that version, although if there is a way of doing so in a later release I am still interested in hearing that..

Comment: Native Excel will not do that.  One method would be to unpivot the Genre columns so as to put all of the Genres into a single column.  In 2010+, this can be done easily using `Power Query` or `Get & Transform`.  In Excel 2007, you'd probably need to write a VBA macro to accomplish this.

Answer (score 0):

I think you would need to separate genres into 2 columns. say Genres A and Genres B, therefore you could apply filter for these columns

Comment: I am afraid you have missed the point: genres already are in two columns - D & E. I just have the title merged across two columns (& 4 for actors). If I filter the columns separately then if I choose 'drama' in column D I get a result set, but it doesn't include any with 'drama' in column E. If I then filter on E there are no 'drama' results as I am already only showing rows with 'drama' in D, and it's not going to also be in E. I am asking for a filter that combines all values from D & E in a drop-down, and then shows results if they are in either column.